# Wearing a mask/the mask/masks

Tags: meaning-in-context

I spotted an ache*(not sure if acne is singular or plural)* on my face after I removed my face mask (coronaviruse). I want to know if the following are correct given the context:

1. It happened because of wearing **the** mask.- I'm saying that a particular mask is responsible for the acne. *(sorry not sure how to use acne)*
2. It happened because of wearing **a** mask.- this is a general statement, I'm saying that masks cause acne.
3. It happened because of wearing mask**s**.- This should be incorrect here since I only have one mask. It would be correct if I were a doctor and had to wear different masks everyday.

Note- I'm not sure if it should be 'an acne' or 'acnes' or just 'acne.'

Comment: Acne is uncountable. I spotted **some acne** on my face.

Comment: If you want to refer to one single occurrence of acne on your face, options include **pimple**, **blackhead** / **whitehead** (depending on the appearance of the outbreak), or **eruption**.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "I spotted some acne", or "I spotted a pimple". The latter fits better if it's a single inflamed follicle.
I think your analysis of the three examples is correct. You could also say "It happened because I wore the mask."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I say 'because I wore the mask' does it refer to a single mask? Am I talking about the specific mask that I wear?

Comment: It can, depending on context and the speakers intention. You could also say "a mask", where it may refer to masks in general.